# What is best and quickest way to fire up a Android 4.4 emulator or virtual box?

Tags: android-emulator

I'm looking to test a few apk's, but was wondering is there a quick android emulator I can fire up easily. A virtual box would also be nice, but i don't think thats widely supported.

Comment: You could try [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).

Comment: Try Genymotion.

Comment: How is that a comment, and "use the official emulator" (which is about the slowest piece of software I've ever used) is an answer?

Comment: @Poldie hence my comment above, android sdk's own is akin to waiting til the cows come home... :D

Comment: @t0mm13b I was referring to your comment (that's my +1) !   
I've given up using the emulator, as it's so easy to use my phone/tablet, but my dev environment is in a VM, so that's a solution of sorts; it's (loads) quicker to bring up Linux Mint in a VM (which has Android Studio and the emulator permanently running) than to fire up the emulator on a bare-metal OS each time

Comment: Oh ok! Was a bit confused by your initial comment. Mind me asking, this is going Off-topic here, but why are you running Linux in a VM with an emulator running inside that? Genymotion is a modified form of virtualbox (VM in itself) running android... genuinely curious question as to your setup, unless its Windows based?

Comment: I only heard about Genymotion in the last few months; I'll give it a go if/when I next feel like using an emulator. I have Linux in a VM on a Windows box because until recently I've done more Windows-related development. I'm a relative newcomer to Linux and prefer it.   I seem to recall thinking installation of Genymotion was a bit of a faff, and looking at their FAQ now I can see why. Not sure about running VirtualBox inside VMWare Player.

Comment: I suppose I could run VirtualBox in the Windows base and see if I can somehow connect Android Studio in the Linux VM to it. Running/debugging wirelessly on my N10/S3 is working pretty well at the moment; not sure what an emulator would give me other than the ability to more easily test different resolutions.